# windows 10 screen turns black on uac prompt and user gets signed off

Tags: windows-10, uac

I have an to me absolutely unknown behavior on one machine with windows 10. If the user wants to run a setup or another executable and windows wants to ask the user for really executing and/or for admin rights for the action the screen turns black. After some seconds the user gets automatically signed off and mostly logged in again (the logging in screen is visible and all open programs are closed).
Googling around didn't bring up any results to this. Does maybe somebody know about this behavior and maybe what could cause this? Maybe a update? **Edit:** The Fall Creators Update / Redstone 3 is not installed. The machine still runs with the Creators Update / Redstone 2

The machine is a HP notebook with pre-installed windows 10, Intel core i7 and Nvidia graphics card. I did remove most of the HP bloatware, when the notebook arrived. This should not be responsible for the behavior, since this happened some months ago.

The behavior showed up in the last days. Before this everything worked as usual/expected for some months. So it was possible to perform tasks which caused this type of prompts.

**Edit2:**
I figured out that winlogon.exe is causing this problem.

Anyway... unfortunately I couldn't examine why exactly it caused this problem, because the notebook started to freeze and having some SSD-issues resulting in not being possible anymore to boot to Windows. I think this issues caused the problem. I'm now trying to perform some recovery.